# Are Neural Tangent Kernels any better than a standard (e.g. RBF) kernel?

Tags: gaussian-process

I've become curious if [NTK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_tangent_kernel)'s are simply a theoretical tool to investigate NN's behavior at infinite width or if they also have any practical value/advantage over regular Gaussian Process kernels?

In other words is there any reason for someone uninterested in NN theory to choose NTK's over say RBF when creating a GP?

P.S. bonus points for a short comparison of RBF vs NTK properties in GPs.